# Run Hungarian Maximum Matching Algorithm with own sets of vertices and show Bipartite Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization, demonstrations

I have come across this demonstration project from https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheHungarianMaximumMatchingAlgorithm/ . How can I supply my own sets of vertices as input so the algorithm can show the augmenting path found in a step-by-step process in the bipartite graph? Also, I need to add weight of each edge as input too. It seems like the source code only generates a number of vertices and no weight of edge is shown in the demonstration. Part of the source code is attached below. I think that's the part that I should add something.

```
Manipulate[
 If[j > f[nn, maxdeg], j = f[nn, maxdeg]];
 SeedRandom[nn + maxdeg 100];
 TraceData = 
  BipartiteMaximumMatchingTraceImages[
   RandomBipartiteGraph[nn/2, nn/2, maxdeg, 1], {}];
 Show[TraceData[[j]], PlotLabel -> None],

 Row[{Control@{{nn, 22, "size of bipartite graph"}, Range[6, 30, 4], 
     Setter}, Spacer[20],
   Control@{{maxdeg, 3, "maximum degree of lower part"}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 
      6}}}],
 {{j, 1, "algorithm step"}, 
  Dynamic[Range@f[nn, maxdeg], SynchronousUpdating -> False], Setter},
 TrackedSymbols :> {nn, maxdeg, j},
 AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2},
```

Comment: Does `FindIndependentEdgeSet` help? It solves the maximum matching problem.

Comment: I think it helps. From https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindIndependentEdgeSet.html , the first application desribes my problem quite well. Did they use a table to store the edges as input? I would like to store about 169 weighted edges in the table.

Comment: Is it possible to show it step-by-step, meaning the graph will gradually show each augmenting path found?